# Error in installing matplotlib library for Windows 10 with pip install commands

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, installation

It gives the following error statements which are too hard for me to understand clearly.
I have installed python 3.8 in this windows 10 machine.
Visual Studio C++ 2019 (community edition) is also installed.

```
C:\Windows\system32>python -m pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/d1/7b12cd79c791348cb0c78ce6e7d16bd72992f13c9f1e8e43d2725a6d8adf/matplotlib-3.1.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\pog66\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\pog66\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\pog66\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\pog66\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in c:\users\pog66\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\pog66\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\pog66\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (41.2.0)
Installing collected packages: matplotlib
    Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\pog66\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pog66\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vuhpppnv\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pog66\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vuhpppnv\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pog66\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oc9ir92r\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\pog66\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vuhpppnv\matplotlib\
    Complete output (505 lines):
    ================================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.1.1]
          python: yes [3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC
                      v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]]
        platform: yes [win32]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
             agg: yes [installing]
           tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl/Tk]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
            dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying lib\pylab.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\afm.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    copying lib\matplotlib\animation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\matplotlib
    ..........
```

Comment: Please show the full error log! The error isn’t in the part you posted.